# Can someon help me find missing figures in papers by Bujalance and Kuusalo?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

There are two papers that i am trying very hard to understand.  They
concern the period matrices of hyperelliptic curves and are just easy
enough so that i have chance of understanding them.

They are  as follows:

"Period Matrices of Accola-Maclachlan and Kulkarni Surfaces" by E. Bujalance
Annales Academiæ Scientiarum Fennicæ
Mathematica
Volumen 25, 2000, 161–177

"Geometric Uniformization in Genus 2" by T. Kuusalo
Annales Academiæ Scientiarum Fennicæ
Series A. I. Mathematica
Volumen 20, 1995, 401–418

Unfortunately both papers rely a goodly amount on figures, and the
figures are missing.  I have gone back to the original publicatoin
journal and attempted to retrieve complete copies from there but the
figures continue to be missing.

I dont suppose that anybody by some chance has an idea of how i could
get hold of these figures?